# How to Directly Go to Editor Groups?

Tags: split

Currently, I'm using <kbd>C-w</kbd><kbd>C-h</kbd>-type of shortcuts to navigate through open editors. However, in VS Code, I'm also used to using shortcuts like <kbd>C-1</kbd> to go to the first editor group, instead of hopping through them all until I reach the first one.

Is there a way of doing it in Vim? How does it work in defining the editor group index when we split both horizontally and vertically?

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by editor group and editor group index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vim doesn't have an equivalent of Visual Studio Code's ["editor groups"](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_editor-groups) or "editors" because what it has—buffers, windows, and tab pages—doesn't map 1-to-1 with what Visual Studio Code has. Therefore, it can't be expected to provide any command for interacting with "editor groups".

When you split windows, all you get is just… more windows, without any notion of window grouping like "columns" or "rows", so all you can do is move your cursor to the desired *window*.

You have quite a bunch of `<C-w>` commands for that under `:help window-move-cursor`.

`n<C-w>w`, where `n` is the number of a window, might help in some cases, but there is *really* no more columns or rows than there are editors or editor groups so you should forget those notions entirely.

Answer (score 2):

You can go to the upper left window using: <kbd>Ctrl w</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>

You can also go to the lower right window using: <kbd>Ctrl w</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Since, personally, I don't use a crazy amount of windows, I think that manually mapping a combination of what the other answers mentioned is probably best: something like <kbd>C-w</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>2C-w</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> for <kbd>C-3</kbd> for example.